# How to set select box height in asp.net for DropDownCheckBoxes

Tags: css, asp.net, .net

I am unable to set Select box height for DropDownCheckBoxes in asp.net. I was able to set SelectBoxWidth, DropDownBoxBoxWidth, DropDownBoxBoxHeight.
I even tried adding SelectBoxCssClass but not working. First image is my current output. I am trying to get output as in second image

Any help appreciated[image: Current Output Image]

[image: I want to get this output]

```
 <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="DdlProject" runat="server"   OnTextChanged="DdlProject_TextChanged"
                         AddJQueryReference="true" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="dd_chk_select" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlProject_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                          <Style SelectBoxWidth="120" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="120"  DropDownBoxBoxHeight="120" DropDownBoxCssClass="btn-default dropdown-toggle" SelectBoxCssClass="btn-default dropdown-toggle dd_chk_select"/>
                          <Texts SelectBoxCaption="Select Project" />
                       </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>

.dd_chk_select {
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
```

}

Comment: in your style try setting the tag as important `height: 100px !important;`

Comment: your welcome, I added it to the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your style try setting the tag as important

```
.dd_chk_select {
    height: 100px !important;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

You said it worked, this means that your height style was being overwritten somewhere.